# LinkageError thrown when attempting to pass instance of class between 2 eclipse plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, classpath

I have found many people with simliar issues but no soultions...basically I have two eclipse plug-ins that both in ther class path rely on the same jar.

The UI plug-in replies on the Driver plug-in (implementing a custom ODA driver and UI for it). Both rely on a jar containing some other classes of mine and is called plugin-dto.jar

When the UI plug-in calls a method on one of the classes in the Driver plug-in that returns an object whose class is found in the plugin-dto jar I get the error:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: Class com/test/reporting/NrDsDriverProvider violates loader constraints
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:576)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:546)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_LockClassLoader(ClasspathManager.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:105)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
```

Any ideas how I get around this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that instances of classes loaded in two different plugins are different, even if they came from the same jar.  The Eclipse Plugin class loader is doing what it is supposed to.   Assuming that Plugin A and Plugin B are both trying to access the same instance of class Z, a couple of solutions to this problem are:

- Create a common plugin, call it D, that contains and exports Z.  Update Plugins A and B to not include the jar for Z and instead load Z from D.
- Set up A and B to use "Buddy Classloading", see http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Context_Class_Loader_Enhancements

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I am looking into the first suggestion since the UI plugin already depends on the Driver plugin I figured surely the UI plugin can inherit the dependencies of the Drvier plugin. Though I am struggling!
I have attempted adding to the 'Export-package' attribute in the MANIFEST the package name of the classes in the jar that the UI plugin needs but that didn't work. Have you any idea how I set this up? Thanks